# Request to server x Reply from server y

Tags: firewall, ip, tcp

I need some advice from you guys:
I'm dealing with a custom loadbalancer/software for which we will use 2 main servers and about 8 slave servers. In short: User sends request to main server, main server will receive and handle the requests, sends a request to a slave server and slave server should send data DIRECTLY to the "user".

User -> Main server

Main server  -> Slave server

Slave server -> User

- The reason for which data should be send directly to the user and not through the main server is because of bandwidth and low budget.

Now I have the following idea's:
-IPinIP, but that is not possible in Layer7 (so far i know there some expensive routers for that)
-IP Spoof, using C/C++ we will make it look like the reply came from main server.

But I was thinking, perhaps the reply "slave server -> User" could just come from a different IP without causing issues in the firewall from the user or his anti-virus. I don't know so well about "home" firewalls/routers and/or anti-virus software. I guess the user machine wouldn't handle it well?

Comment: I presume the `TCP` tag means that the connection is TCP? What protocol is layered on top of TCP?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it depends on how the custom load balancer(I guess the master server as indicated in your schematic) and the slave servers application may be configured. There are two principles which are often seen in load balancers to make an actual design around request/reply-routing:

1) If you can tell the main server not to use its own ip address as the source ip, but instead the clients ip (such as was in the packet as it came to the main server in the first place, as per your schematic) when passing the packet to the slaves. The slave server will naturally send its reply directly to the client rather than through the main. This is a rather common function to see in load balancers, we network guys often call source rewrites "source nat" rather than ip spoofing to distinguish the benign intent, and with which you ought to be able to make some interesting googles on the subject.

2) Another design option is to embed metainformation similar to the X-Forwarded-For header in http or the remote_addr/remote_host(can´t remember which) field in ajp which are used to carry the original client ip address as part of the data field even when it has been replaced by an intermediary host address in the ip packet. If something similar is possible to achieve using the protocol you are using, your master servers would need to inject that metainformation into a field of choice. The application on your slave servers would need to be instructed to send the reply to the address in that field instead of to the source address in the ip packet. One of the perks of this design is that it makes for excellent logging since you get access to all node addresses which have been involved in a particular stream.

This is by way of principle, in practice you may stumble a bit if the client expects the reply from the slave to be a part of the same session as the request (and so on and so forth). It all depends on the expectations of the protocol you are trying to pass, and what infrastructure you have around your service to puzzle things together for you :-)